# terrible recruitment should/how I complain

Tags: colleagues, recruitment, human-resources

I am a techlead to a rather complex technical(not many functional requirements, predominantly non functional) backend application. The project is very complex with regards of the people working on it:

- Multicultural
- Age difference between employees
- Challenging communication

Out of 7 people team only 3 are developing activly. All three are supposed to be seniour level developers. In reality one is seniour, the second is producing with seniour level quality, but the output is half of what I expect from a seniour developer. The third one does not produce code with the quality. expected from a seniour developer. Prety much we are going after him and fixing up his things.

With this landscape we are feeling lack of developer force. We don't code enough and it is challenging to meet the deadlines and everything else.

All 3 of us are consultants, the other members of the team are internal employees , but they are not activly developing.

We have recieved a new employee that is supposed to be a developer. The new internal employee has previously been a consultant for the same company, so his work is visible in github history. Which project he has been programmer to and what he has developed.

I went through his code in order to understand who am I dealing with what is strong sides are and he has not developed anything meaningfull outside of name refactoring and fixing up some texts here and there last two years. Now he is a assigned to a realy tough backend project with high technical complexity. I seriously doubt that anything good may come out of his stay with us based on his github history. I have no idea how this organisation having his track record more or less documented in githib has actualy recruited him and then assigned him to so complex backend system as the one we are developing.

Should I complain and how, considering that I am consultant and I am the techlead of the team?

Comment: "Out of 7 people team only 3 are developing activly" As the team lead, what have you done about this? If the answer is "nothing", you're picking the wrong fight here.

Comment: The team has history. The 3 of the 4 person are 60+ 1 is functioning as domain expert, another is doing maintanance and support. The third is almost retired. And the forth is..... a mistake... I mean no idea what he is doing in the team, but even though I complained about him he is still there.

The problem is we dont have enough force , development force and instead of developer we are getting.... a joke of a developer.

Comment: I understand that. But what have you, the team lead, done about this up to now other than "complained"? How have **you** communicated the problems to management? What actions have **you** taken to improve the performance of the team?

Comment: I am not a team lead, I am a tech lead. I am responsible ONLY for the technical solution.
Still I have done a lot. I have defined the solution of course and done changes to the team with regards of the process we are using. We have transition from a brutal waterfall model to a relatively fast agile. But I and not responsible for the personal. So I can not see what more can I do outside of complain when someone is not doing his job.

Comment: Is anyone on the team involved in the recruitment of these people?

Answer (score 4):

If as you say in comments:

- Your role is *solely* responsible for technical aspects with zero responsibility at all for the people side, and
- You have already raised the issues with management and you have been ignored

then there's almost certainly nothing you can do. For one reason or another, management have decided not to act on your advice. At this point, you have the choice of whether to continue to accept their coin, and their decisions on how to run their business, or to find another role.